# Inserting data into a cloudfoundry mysql database using vmc tunnel

Tags: mysql, privileges, cloud-foundry, vmc

I am trying to **insert data into a cloudfoundry mysql database** as follows:

```
vmc tunnel myapp --port 10000 mysql
```

Then:

```
mysql> source /home/julien/Documents/donnees/projets/Site-Rencontres/java/src/main/resources/misc/sql/geolocation.sql
ERROR 1142 (42000): INSERT command denied to user 'udYra*****'@'172.30.*.*' for table 'geolocation'
```

What strikes me is that the user I retrieved using `java.lang.System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");` is different from the one above:

```
"user":"ukqM8******"
```

My question is twofold:

1. How can I prepopulate the cloudfoundry database with data?
2. Why is the above user different from the one I retrieved from the VCAP_SERVICES env variable?

**EDIT**: I was able to succefully connect to mysql using vmc tunnel's `none` option and then pointing to port `10000` from the mysql client. I am now running into mysql privileges issues and I opened another thread here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the users are different is that Caldecott uses a different binding to the application where you inspected VCAP_SERVICES.